# Iam having trouble with my program. i am trying print out all prime numbers up to 10,000, but it won't print out past 1,2, and 3

Tags: java

here's my program to figure out all of the prime numbers up to 10,000

```
public class Prime {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        boolean prime = true;

        for(int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {//possible prime numbers
            for(int a = 2; a <= i/2; a++) {
                if(i % a == 0){
                    prime = false;
                }
            }
            if(prime)
                System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

When you set your `prime` flag to `false` it stays `false` forever. You need to set it `true` at the beginning of each new run of your outer `for` loop.

```
boolean prime = true;
for(int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++){
    prime = true;  // ADD THIS LINE !!
    for(...){...}
    if(prime)
        System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

Comment: To add to Arctic's answer, you are never setting prime back to true. Once it encounters its first non-prime (4), it sets prime to false and therefore can never be true again.